# What is the significance behind the black & white photo Sam picks up?

Tags: plot-explanation, inbred

Regarding the scene (about 15 minutes in) in *Inbred* when the group arrives at their Mortlake cottage for the first time, what is the significance behind the black & white photo Sam the girl picks up?

It appears to show boy scouts (?), a man and possibly an animal. But I cannot tell what's going on in the photo that makes Sam so uncomfortable before Dwight frightens her from behind.

Does anyone have a better eye than me here to answer?